# Perl Date in this format

Tags: php, perl, datetime

How do I get date & time in this format in perl? `Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z`
`T` represents the time part and `Z` represents the time zone.

For example, `2012-11-28T17:21:11+0100`

I think in php you can do using `gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TIMTOWTDI

Using POSIX strftime

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
use POSIX qw/ strftime /;

say strftime( "%Y-%m-%dT%T%z", localtime );
```

One Liner:

```
perl -MPOSIX -E 'say strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%T%z", localtime);'
```

Outputs:

```
2014-09-05T20:11:34-0400
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Time::Piece`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Piece.html):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Time::Piece;

print localtime->strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z'), "\n";
```

Outputs:

```
2014-09-05T16:39:54-0700
```

Answer (score 2):

one of possible solutions:

```
use 5.010;
use warnings;
use Time::Piece;
say localtime->strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%T%z");
```

or oneliner

```
perl -MTime::Piece -E 'say localtime->strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%T%z");'
```

prints

```
2014-09-06T01:36:39+0200
```